# Windows 7: "Open with" context menu not always available when I want it

Tags: windows, vim

I recently formatted my hard drive, and right now there's not much on here except a clean Windows 7 install and the most recent version of Vim for Windows. I told Vim to install its own context menu, so I can right click files and tell Windows to edit them with Vim.

Not only is this feature absent much (not all) of the time, so too is the "open with" option a lot of the time.

How can I get both of these options to show up consistently in the context menu?

Comment: Have you tried first left-clicking inside the directory in Explorer? Sometimes I don't have the option, but it will show up if I click on a file (any file) inside the directory first.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can get the 'open with...' option if you hold SHIFT while right-clicking.  But there's an answer below giving some registry keys to tweak, perhaps that'll be better.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you'll need

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\vim]
@="Open with Vim"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\vim\command]
@="C:\\location\\of\\your\\vim.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: I've used this successfully, just had to change the `'%1'`to `"%1"`.

You should create a Key with Default Value `vim` in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` and a key `command` inside `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\vim` with Default Value `LOCATION_OF_YOUR_vim.exe_HERE "%1"`.